# How to transfer a numerical value in Mathematica into a symbolic fraction with sufficiently large precision?

Tags: symbolic, precision-and-accuracy, rounding

Suppose I have a number $0.26630939883535015$ and want to transfer it into a symbolic fraction by truncating it first. The way I do it is first `Round` it and then `Rationalize` it as the following code shows

```mathematica
Rationalize@Round[0.26630939883535015, 0.00001]
```

with output $26631/100000$. So far so good. Since I want higher precision, so I execute the following code

```mathematica
Rationalize@Round[0.26630939883535015, 0.000001]
```

Notice that I change $0.00001$ into $0.000001$ inside `Round` function. The result now becomes $0.266309$. It does not work. Then I tried to use the following code

```mathematica
Rationalize[Round[0.26630939883535015, 0.000001], 0]
```

However, the output is $7085634719/26606816589$ but I expect the output to be $266309/1000000$.

Is there some other method that I can achieve the goal?

Comment: **want to transfer it into a symbolic fraction by truncating it first.**  Why truncate? You lose accuracy. The whole point of symbolic computation is that you can work with exact values as is all the time, unlink Fortran or Matlab.

Comment: I would do `SetAccuracy[0.26630939883535015, Infinity]` which gives `4797403637440575/18014398509481984`

Comment: @Nasser Thank you for your comment. For the specific problem I considered, losing some precision is harmless to me but a nicer representation of the number(such as 266309/1000000 instead of 4797403637440575/18014398509481984) is more important.  But anyway, I don't know the method you mentioned and it might be very useful someday for me :)

Comment: @Nasser Furthermore, you mentioned that you don't want to lose accuracy and provided a method `SetAccuracy[0.26630939883535015, Infinity]` which implies your method does not lose accuracy. However, I think your method also loses accuracy since the result of `26630939883535015/100000000000000000 - 4797403637440575/18014398509481984` is not zero!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use exact numbers in the second argument of [`Round`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Round.html)

```
expr = 0.26630939883535015;

Round[expr, 10^-#] & /@ Range[6]

(* {3/10, 27/100, 133/500, 2663/10000, 26631/100000, 266309/1000000} *)
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much but I didn't find it first in the documentation. It seems that if you use a decimal as the second argument of `Round`, it will return a decimal; if you use a fraction as the second argument of `Round`, then it will return a fraction.

Comment: From the documentation, "If a is not a real number, Round[x, a] is given by the formula Round[x, a] == a Round[x/a]"

Answer (score 9):

You don't need the rounding, because `Rationalize` has a 2nd parameter:

```
Table[Rationalize[0.26630939883535015, 1/10^n], {n, 10}]
```

[image]